# Qual o valor default de MAIL_ENCRYPTION no Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel

Minha dúvida se resume a definição do `MAIL_ENCRYPTION`, no arquivo `.env` temos `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null` e dentro do arquivo `config\mail.php` linha 74 temos o trecho:

```
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
```

Considerando que no arquivo `.env` `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` foi definida para `null`, seu valor final será `tls`?

Fiquei em dúvida pois a atribuição de `null` me confundiu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse caso será o que está definido no `.env` (`null`).

```
> php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.8.17 (PHP 7.0.26 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> config('mail.encryption')
=> null
```

Para usar o valor padrão, comente seu `.env` com `#MAIL_ENCRYPTION=` ou remova a linha de vez.

```
> php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.8.17 (PHP 7.0.26 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> config('mail.encryption')
=> "tls"
```